# Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'JSArray<String>': type 'JSArray<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I was learning the map structure with dart, this code I wrote gave the error " Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'JSArray': type 'JSArray' is not a subtype of type 'String", how can I solve it, thanks in advance

```
void main(){
  var sepet =  Map();
  sepet ["kola"]=["2.5 LT"];
  sepet ["süt"]=["yarım yaglı"];
  sepet ["mısır"]=["3 kg"];
  sepet ["bmw"]=["3.20 "];

  

  for (var key in sepet.keys){
    print(key + ":" + sepet[key]);
  }
  for (var value in sepet.keys){
    print(value + " : " + sepet[value]);
  }
   
}
```

Comment: `sepet["kola"]=["2.5 LT"];` You are assigning a `List<String>` here, I suspect you want to assign just the `String` instead `sepet["kola"]="2.5 LT";`.

Comment: actually no i get this error

Comment: Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'other')

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is converting your map to `String`

```
void main(){
  var sepet =  Map();
  sepet["kola"]=["2.5 LT"];
  sepet["süt"]=["yarım yaglı"];
  sepet["mısır"]=["3 kg"];
  sepet["bmw"]=["3.20 "];

  

  for (var key in sepet.keys){
    print(key.toString() + ":" + sepet[key].toString());
  }
  for (var value in sepet.keys){
    print(value.toString() + " : " + sepet[value].toString());
  }
   
}
```